# How to configure KeePass's AutoFill feature to ignore the browser's name?

Tags: google-chrome, keepass, auto-form-fill

I use the AutoFill feature in KeePass, which chooses which entry to fill by detecting its name in the focused window's title.

Therefore, when I activate AutoFill on any page in Google Chrome, KeePass detects "Google" in the window's title and either :

- if the website is in my password database, shows me a dialog to choose an entry to fill, between the site I was on and Google,
- if the website is unknown, autofills my Google credentials in this random website.

This is not very practical and leaves me worried about the security of my Google account.

How can I configure KeePass to ignore the " - Google Chrome" part of a window's title ?

Comment: I suppose you are using it under Windows, but, which version, 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I use version 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option under the `Advanced` tab which toogles matching if a keepass entry's title is contained in the target window title which you can turn off to avoid that behabiour (at least under keepass 2.x, I do not longer have 1.x installed so I cannot confirm there is such option in the older version)

Nevertheless, that could render most of your auto-type features disabled if you do not customize each entry to have a `target window`, so you might need to modify most of your entries.

A workaround could be changing your google's title to be "My main Google account" (or whatever you like) to avoid the matching in "Google Chrome" and keep the `advanced` option I mentioned early enabled (you may still need to add `target window`(s) to match your google's entry.